# Occasional Http requests timeout on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda, axios, timeout

I've got an AWS lambda (as node.js) that is triggered by cron every 3 minutes. it purpose is to monitor some of our API's services, so it is sends http requests. Issue is, in 20% of the cases the http request times out. when I run it locally, or manually (by using the Test feature on AWS console) everything works ok. I tried to increase the timeout option but with no success.

Error Im getting is:

> timeout of 5000ms exceeded at createError (/var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js

Error Details:

> 2021-08-30T09:06:08.029Z  841332b5-d8c1-49dc-8caa-f57215ed5440    ERROR   PortalApiSql_Error Error: timeout of 5000ms exceeded
> at createError (/var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
> at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:280:16)
> at RedirectableRequest.emit (events.js:400:28)
> at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:166:12)
> at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
> at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7) {
> config: {
> url: '/health/sql',
> method: 'get',
> headers: {
> Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
> ApiToken: '*****-******-******-******',
> 'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.1'
> },
> baseURL: 'https://apidev.myportal.com/v1',
> transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
> transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
> timeout: 5000,
> adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
> xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
> xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
> maxContentLength: -1,
> maxBodyLength: -1,
> validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
> data: undefined
> },
> code: 'ECONNABORTED',
> request: <ref *1> Writable {
> _writableState: WritableState {
> objectMode: false,
> highWaterMark: 16384,
> finalCalled: false,
> needDrain: false,
> ending: false,
> ended: false,
> finished: false,
> destroyed: false,
> decodeStrings: true,
> defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
> length: 0,
> writing: false,
> corked: 0,
> sync: true,
> bufferProcessing: false,
> onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
> writecb: null,
> writelen: 0,
> afterWriteTickInfo: null,
> buffered: [],
> bufferedIndex: 0,
> allBuffers: true,
> allNoop: true,
> pendingcb: 0,
> prefinished: false,
> errorEmitted: false,
> emitClose: true,
> autoDestroy: true,
> errored: null,
> closed: false
> },
> _events: [Object: null prototype] {
> response: [Array],
> error: [Array],
> socket: [Function: destroyOnTimeout]
> },
> _eventsCount: 3,
> _maxListeners: undefined,
> _options: {
> maxRedirects: 21,
> maxBodyLength: 10485760,
> protocol: 'https:',
> path: '/v1/health/sql',
> method: 'GET',
> headers: [Object],
> agent: undefined,
> agents: [Object],
> auth: undefined,
> hostname: 'apidev.myportal.com',
> port: null,
> nativeProtocols: [Object],
> pathname: '/v1/health/sql'
> },
> _ended: true,
> _ending: true,
> _redirectCount: 0,
> _redirects: [],
> _requestBodyLength: 0,
> _requestBodyBuffers: [],
> _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
> _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
> _events: [Object: null prototype],
> _eventsCount: 2,
> _maxListeners: undefined,
> outputData: [],
> outputSize: 0,
> writable: true,
> destroyed: true,
> _last: true,
> chunkedEncoding: false,
> shouldKeepAlive: false,
> _defaultKeepAlive: true,
> useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
> sendDate: false,
> _removedConnection: false,
> _removedContLen: false,
> _removedTE: false,
> _contentLength: 0,
> _hasBody: true,
> _trailer: '',
> finished: true,
> _headerSent: true,
> socket: [TLSSocket],
> _header: 'GET /v1/health/sql HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
> 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
> 'ApiToken: ******-******-******-******-\r\n' +
> 'User-Agent: axios/0.21.1\r\n' +
> 'Host: apidev.myportal.com\r\n' +
> 'Connection: close\r\n' +
> '\r\n',
> _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
> _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
> agent: [Agent],
> socketPath: undefined,
> method: 'GET',
> maxHeaderSize: undefined,
> insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
> path: '/v1/health/sql',
> _ended: false,
> res: null,
> aborted: true,
> timeoutCb: null,
> upgradeOrConnect: false,
> parser: [HTTPParser],
> maxHeadersCount: null,
> reusedSocket: false,
> host: 'apidev.myportal.com',
> protocol: 'https:',
> _redirectable: [Circular *1],
> [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
> [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
> [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
> [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
> },
> _currentUrl: 'https://apidev.myportal.com/v1/health/sql',
> _timeout: Timeout {
> _idleTimeout: 5000,
> _idlePrev: null,
> _idleNext: null,
> _idleStart: 149306,
> _onTimeout: [Function (anonymous)],
> _timerArgs: undefined,
> _repeat: null,
> _destroyed: true,
> [Symbol(refed)]: true,
> [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
> [Symbol(asyncId)]: 63,
> [Symbol(triggerId)]: 59
> },
> [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
> },
> response: undefined,
> isAxiosError: true,
> toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
> }

I've simplified the code (simplified code also gets the timeout error),

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: PortalApiUrl,
    timeout: AxiosTimeout,
    headers: { ApiToken: PortalApiToken },
});

try {
    console.log("before req ");
    console.log(WATCHERS_CONFIGURATION.PortalApiSql.Path);
    const response = await axiosInstance.get(WATCHERS_CONFIGURATION.PortalApiSql.Path);
    console.log(`recieved ${response}`);
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
    };
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error: ", error);
    return {
        statusCode: 500,
    };
}
};
```

Comment: Is the Lambda function configured to run in a VPC?

Comment: yes. it has a VPC and a security group with outbound rule for all protocols and ports

Comment: It sounds like you have it configured to run in multiple VPC subnets, and at least one of those subnets does not have a route to a NAT Gateway. You either need to configure it to only run in subnets with a route to a NAT Gateway, or completely remove the VPC configuration from the function.

Comment: 10x! It was indeed the VPC subnets, I had one public subnet & 2 privates subnets (with route to NAT) configured. removing the public one fixed the issue.

Comment: Why does removing the public subnet resolve the issue? @Ofir